# Bootstrap class navbar-right not working correctly?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, haml, frontend

I am attempting to make a navbar with a logout option on the right of the page:

| Home | Account Settings |                                                | Logout |

Here is the haml code I am using:

```
%html
  %head
    %title Pick 'Em
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'media' => 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body
    %div.container
      %nav.nav.navbar.navbar-default{:role => "navigation"}
        .container-fluid
          %ul.nav.nav-tabs
            %li
              - if !user_signed_in?
                = link_to "Home", authenticated_root_path, :id => 'home'
              - else
                = link_to "Home", unauthenticated_root_path, :id => 'home'
              - if !user_signed_in?
                %li
                  = link_to "Login", users_sign_in_path, :id => 'login'
              - else
                %li
                  = link_to "Account Settings", users_account_settings_path, :id => 'account_settings'
          %ul.nav.nav-tabs.navbar-right  
            %li
              = link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :id => 'logout'

      - if !notice.nil?
        %p.notice= notice

      - if !alert.nil?
        %p.alert= alert

      = yield
```

Despite my use of navbar-right for the Logout tab, the navbar renders as follows:

| Home | Account Settings |  | Logout |

There is a separation between Account Settings and Logout, but Logout is not pushed to the right.  The nav spans the full width of the page, but I navbar-right does not push to the right edge as I would expect.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `navbar-nav` class inside of the `%ul`

```
%ul.nav.navbar-nav.nav-tabs
```

[Here is a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Beengie/3dzrq8jt/) of a working one to maybe help you understand what is going on with your instance. You might need to stretch out the screen to see the navbar snap to the right instead of being stacked. It stacks due to there being 2 different lists in the navbar.